# Milwaukee fuel M18 CCS55 battery saw

Tags: repair

I recently got a Milwaukee M18 fuel battery saw. It worked  for a few cuts but now when I depress the trigger on the saw, it clicks and does not turn. It has a safety switch incorporated and when you press that the built in light illuminates but the saw does not spin. Can I fix it myself?

Comment: You have checked that the battery is charged?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have a bad switch so the question is how good are you at taking things apart and then putting them back together?

My first step would be to check out the warranty from the manufacturer and from the store where you purchased it. They usually have very good customer service where tools are concerned but if you try to fix it first, you'll void any warranties.

Comment: Until the OP verifies that he fully charged the battery,  that the battery is good,  and that he can manually move the chain (it's not jammed),  this is the last thing I would check.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  I'm guessing the OP checked these very basic first steps before asking the question.  I've replaced about a dozen saw switched, very common problem.They can get pitted very fast.

Comment: "You must be new here"  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  I do tend to give people the benefit of the doubt.     I should know better by now. :-)